# split string with comma and newspace in 2d or jagged array and access items in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split, text-parsing

Hi there I have a text file like this, many lines 2 columns

```
CF7CED1BF035345269118A15EF2D45A06, product1
CF7CED1BF035345269118A15EF2D45A09, product2
....
...
...
...
```

I need to split this and access each field, more precise I need to make a loop that creates many files like product1.txt product2.txt etc and will enclose the codes on its left.

So I need to create files with filenames of columns [2] of all lines and enclose the column[1] as value of each line

I know how to do basic stuff in arrays, like read all lines and store them, but i don't know how to make a loop that will read both field 1 then 2 of LINE 1, create the file and store (I know how to read and save to file) and go on on next LINE 2 and go on field 1 and field 2 again and so on.

Someone suggested using jagged arrays would be faster than 2d arrays

Comment: You could just use an array of (filename, file handle) pairs.  When you read a line in, search the array for the filename, and if it's in there, write to that file, otherwise, open a new file, append the file name and handle (or file object I should say) to the array, and write to the new file.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use
>   ReadAllLines, you must  wait for the whole array of strings be
>   returned before you can access the  array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient."

```
string path_read = @"c:\read\file.txt";
//Path to save resulting files.
string path = @"c:\temp\";
char[] comma = new char[1]{','};
//ASSUMPTION: Your every row has comma separated 2 values. 
//Do a for loop.
//Code now use File.ReadLines
foreach (var currentLine in File.ReadLines(path_read))
{
   string[] itemArray = currentLine.Split(comma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   // Your item array now has 2 values from 2 columns in the same row. 
   // Do whatever with it.
   File.WriteAllText(path+itemArray[1]+".txt", itemArray[0], Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to keep the contents for any further use? if the intent is to read and the save the contents to separate files then there is no need for a separate array.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"input.txt"))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var inputText = reader.ReadLine();
                var splitText = inputText.Split(',');

                File.AppendAllLines(splitText[1] + ".txt", new List<string> {splitText[0]});
            }
        }
```